# Wrong site appears in Nginx

Tags: debian, configuration, nginx, domain

I have a Debian Linux server with nginx configured for several sites (`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`), every site showing on its own domain.

Now when I remove a site from `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`, querying the the domain of the removed site displays not something like ("This domain is not configured") but some another site (configured for a totally different domain).

I want to remove a site from my server, but instead of proper removal I see it replaced with another site.

Here is my config for one of my sites, for an example:

```
# cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/homepage | grep -vE '^\s*#'

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;


    root /var/www/homepage/web/;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name portonvictor.org;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you explicitly define a default server, `nginx` will use the first server with a matching port (for any request where there is no explicit `server_name` match). See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details.

You should create a catch all server block, for example:

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One Liner to server blank page by default:

```
echo >> /var/www/html/index.html
cat << 'EOF' >/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html/;
        index index.html;
}
server {
        listen 443 default_server;
        listen [::]:443 default_server;
        root /var/www/html/;
        index index.html;
}
EOF
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
systemctl restart nginx
systemctl status nginx
```