# nginx is loading wrong website when service isn´t working

Tags: networking, nginx

I have a webserver with two services and an nginx running. Each of the services should be accessible by a URL. This should be done by a configuration file per service:

**jenkins.conf**

```
server {
    listen                      [::]:443 ssl;
    listen                      443 ssl;
    server_name                 jenkins.<URL>.de www.jenkins.<URL>.de;

    access_log                  /var/log/nginx/jenkins_access.log;
    error_log                   /var/log/nginx/jenkins_error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass              http://localhost:8100;
        proxy_read_timeout      90;
    }

    ssl_certificate ...fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key ...privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

**chirpstack.conf**

```
server {
    listen                      80;
    server_name                 chirpstack.<URL>.de www.chirpstack.<URL>.de;

    client_max_body_size        0;

    access_log                  /var/log/nginx/chirpstack_access.log;
    error_log                   /var/log/nginx/chirpstack_error.log;

location / {
    proxy_pass              http://localhost:8102;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
    proxy_set_header        X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
  }
}
```

I have the scenario where my Jenkins isn´t running (in case of an error or something else) and I have entered the URL `jenkins.<URL>.de` in my browser. But the browser isn´t showing any sort of error or something like that. Instead, he is showing the login page from my ChirpStack service.

[image]

Why is the browser loading the wrong web service when one service isn´t running? How can I avoid it?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/288495/30851

Comment: Thank you. It´s exactly what I need.